# AWS Elastic Beanstalk app initial access is not secure, but subsequent redirect is

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk (with load balancer) to support a Wordpress site. I have setup SSL through the Certificate Manager (ACM) and enabled the load balancer to listen on Port 443 for HTTPS.
I have also tried to force HTTPS on my Wordpress site by adding the following lines to the `wp_config.php` in my source bundle (as suggested by many posts):

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

However, my problem is that when I try to access my site, the initial access is not secure, ie a HTTP connection, but when I try to navigate to other pages and back on my site, the connection immediately becomes a secure HTTPS connection. I am wondering what can I do to resolve this issue such that upon initial access to the site, HTTPS is forced. 
I also ran into "Too many redirects" errors before because of trying to force HTTPS and Wordpress makes it a bit tricky doing that, so I am trying to avoid that. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Set the redirect on the load balancer; have the listener on port 80 redirect to 443.

Comment: @hephalump For the listener on port 80, what should the instance protocol be, should it still be HTTP?

Comment: Yes. In the console, the dropdown will give you an option to redirect instead of forward.

Comment: @hephalump I am not sure if I did the right thing. So for my LB configurations on beanstalk, I have 2 listeners:
1. HTTP 80 -> HTTP 80 
2. HTTPS 443 -> HTTP 80 SSL: xxxxxxxxx
So what are the changes I should make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add elastic beanstalk extensions to your environment. Typically you would include an `.ebextensions` folder in the root of your app to include each of your extensions. ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html))

If you're running nginx as your proxy server which I'll assume you are, add a file called `10-nginx.config` to the extensions directory.

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf":
    content: |
      server {
          listen 80 default_server;

          server_name _;

          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
```

However you should also consider HTTPS termination on your load balancer & having the application running on port 80 within the environment network.

Docs on this are here; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html